# unable to inject seam cache provider

Tags: caching, seam, ehcache

Env: Seam 2.2, ehcache-core 2.1.0

I tried injecting the CacheProvider using the following call in my bean scoped for session

```
    @In CacheProvider cacheProvider;

    WEB-INF\components.xml contains the following line to enable the cache provider
    <cache:eh-cache-provider/>

The above configuration seems to return a null value for the cache provider


Using the cache provider like this         
CacheProvider cacheProvider = CacheProvider.instance();
throws the following warning

    15:29:27,586 WARN [CacheManager] Creating a new instance of CacheManager using
    the diskStorePath "C:\DOCUME~1\user5\LOCALS~1\Temp\" which is already used by an
    existing CacheManager.
    The source of the configuration was net.sf.ehcache.config.generator.Configuratio
    nSource$DefaultConfigurationSource@15ed0f9.
    The diskStore path for this CacheManager will be set to C:\DOCUME~1\user5\LOCALS
    ~1\Temp\\ehcache_auto_created_1276682367586.
    To avoid this warning consider using the CacheManager factory methods to create
    a singleton CacheManager or specifying a separate ehcache configuration (ehcache
    .xml) for each CacheManager instance.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I am using ehcache-core.jar would I also need the ehcache.jar in the lib folder?

Comment: Just for curiosity: Have you ever used some Cache provider before ??? You said your @In-jected component **seems to return null** It can not return null because required attribute from @In annotation is, by default, true **which means it can not be null**. Otherwise you will get an Exception Thrown by Seam. Which Tutorial do you follow ???

Comment: It doesn't seem to throw an exception, the cacheProvider is just null. Query cache and the 2nd level cache just seems to work fine though

Comment: am running out of options here, still unable to figure out the cause of this issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind net.sf.ehcache.Cache **needs to be on the classpath** (I am not sure but I Think ehcache-core.jar contains this class) if you want to use EhCahceProvider. Here goes its signature

```
@Name("org.jboss.seam.cache.cacheProvider")
@Scope(APPLICATION)
@BypassInterceptors
@Install(value = false, precedence=BUILT_IN, classDependencies="net.sf.ehcache.Cache")
@AutoCreate
public class EhCacheProvider extends CacheProvider<CacheManager> {
```

Notice classDependencies attribute. Its documentation is clear

> Indicates that the component *should not be installed* **unless** *the the given class definitions are available on the classpath*

So if your classpath contains net.sf.ehcache.Cache **you do not need to declare**

```
<cache:eh-cache-provider/>
```

And as it is Application scoped, you can retrieve, besides @In-jection, by using

```
ApplicationContext.getContext().get("cacheProvider");
```

**UPDATE**

First of all

- remove <cache:eh-cache-provider/> declaration. I said you why (see above)

Second of all

- Although i am pretty sure CacheProvider **can not be null** because @In required attribute is, by default, true, which cannot be null. Inside your business method, Make sure your CacheProvider is not null

  assert cacheProvider != null

Third of all

- I Think you **do not need to call cacheProvider.instance() method**. If its default scope is Application. **Why do you want to retrieve another CacheProvider ???** It does not make sense.

Fourth of all

- **It is not an exception**. Its is just a warning message because you is trying to use more than one cache provider where **both use the same space in memory**

Comment: net.sf.ehcache.Cache is part of ehcache-core.jar and is present in ear\lib folder.

I have tried the following methods and none seem to work
        // CacheProvider cacheProvider = CacheProvider.instance();
or
        CacheProvider cacheProvider = (CacheProvider) Contexts
                .getApplicationContext().get("cacheProvider");
or
@In CacheProvider cacheProvider;

Comment: @Joshua Make sure war lib folder does not contain ehcache-core.jar once it is stored in ear lib folder

Comment: the jar is present only in ear\lib folder

Comment: I did remove the <cache:eh-cache-provider/> declaration and it still comes up with a NullPointer Exception.

Comment: @Joshua. I believe you. On weekend, i will Try it by myself what you are trying to do. But let me know: which App server do you use ??? EAR or WAR ???

Comment: JBoss 5.1.0, JDK 6, Seam 2.2.0, ehcache-core 2.0.1, standard EAR file containing JPA entity classes in a ejb module and a set of xhtml files. Thanks for all the support you have given so far.

Comment: @Joshua Which Tutorial do you follow ??? Do you use Ajax ??? Do you use JBoss connection pool ??? plain JPA or Hibernate ???

Comment: We had the same problem, the third post in the following post fixed our issue. We have forgotten the schema import inside of the <components>-tag: http://www.seamframework.org/57939.lace